# X-axis minor gridlines still not showing even after trying all solutions

Tags: python, matplotlib

My x-axis minor gridlines are not showing, this is my code

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.minorticks_on()
plt.semilogx(data_x1,data_y1,"red")
plt.semilogx(data_x2,data_y2,"blue")
ax.grid(b=True, which='major',axis="both", color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor',axis="both", color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.2)
plt.xlabel("frequency(Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Iramp(dB)")
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YilSh.png)

Comment: I don't have time to investigate this better, but I ran the code and the minor ticks are present, together with the grid lines associated with them. The problem is that the x-axis is too "zoomed out". Try zooming in and they will appear.

If you wanna fix this you need to figure out how to force matplotlib to always show the minor tickmarks, even when you zoom out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Either I'm not sure of what you want, or your code is actually working correctly. The minor grid lines are those between the powers of 10. I made a little example to show a comparison of your plot with the minor grid lines on and off.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data_x1  = np.linspace(0,2,10)
data_x2  = np.linspace(0,4,10)
data_y1  = np.random.rand(10)
data_y2  = np.random.rand(10)

fig, axall =plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))

# your code with some changes
ax = axall[0]
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.semilogx(data_x1,data_y1,"red")
ax.semilogx(data_x2,data_y2,"blue")
ax.grid(b=True, which='major',axis="both", color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor',axis="both", color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.2)
ax.set_xlabel("frequency(Hz)")
ax.set_ylabel("Iramp(dB)")

# code to make the plot on the right.
ax = axall[1]
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.semilogx(data_x1,data_y1,"red")
ax.semilogx(data_x2,data_y2,"blue")
ax.grid(b=True, which='major',axis="both", color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
# ax.grid(b=True, which='minor',axis="both", color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.2)
ax.set_xlabel("frequency(Hz)")
ax.set_ylabel("Iramp(dB)")
plt.show()
```

Note how I commented out your minor grid lines.

[image]

Comment: For me it doesn't show the minor grids on x axis as you can see in my figure.